# No day without its curse

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, churban-destruction, curse, tractate-sotah

The Gemara (Sotah 48a) says, *“from the day that the Beis HaMikdosh was destroyed, there has been no day without its **curse**.”*

1a) What does the Gemara mean?

1b) What does *it's **curse*** mean?

Comment: The curse could be living without the Beis hamikdash

Comment: It refers to the painful puns that start appearing Rosh Chodesh Adar here.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ramchal in Da'as Tevunos (Simanim 40 and 142) understands this to be a symptom of the *hester panim*, the hiding of Hashem's presence, that coincided (resulted?) from the destruction of the Beis HaMikdosh.  It is an expression of the relationship between the general quality of life in the world and the expression of Hashem's presence in the world.  When Hashem's presence is hidden, which happened with the destruction of the Temple, "curse," or deficiency and ruin, increased in the world.

> מה שעתה בעבור רוב הסתר הפנים נפסדו הדיעות ונתקלקלו כל המעשים, ומזה נמשך גם כן בבריות עצמם הקלקול והפסדות, כענין שאמרו (סוטה מח ע"א), "ניטל טעם הפירות" וכו', וכל שאר הדברים הרעים שספרו לנו רז"ל